# Rails taking wrong mysql path on Mac

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, ruby-on-rails-4

A rails application was created by freelancer outsourced by our company. He created the application on windows. When we try to run it on Macbook pro, it gives the following error:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'`(2) (Mysql2::Error)`
```

Now clearly, since I installed mysql via Homebrew, location of mysql on my system is `/usr/local/bin/mysql` and not `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

**How can I get this working and what all commands will I have to use to fix this up?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share `config/database.yml` content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change the `mysql` socket in `config/database.yml` to your mac one like :

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: xxxx
  database: xxxx
  socket: /usr/local/bin/mysql.sock
```